# Why App is Crashed when Change Uiimage Color

Tags: swift, uiimage

I Have Changed Color Of Uiimage But App is crashed. I do this code in a loop. I have Added Autoreleasepool but not solve my problem.

```
func withColor(_ color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    //this method is extendtion of UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
    guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), let cgImage = cgImage else { return self }
    color.setFill()
    ctx.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
    ctx.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    ctx.clip(to: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height), mask: cgImage)
    ctx.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    guard let colored = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return self }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return colored
}
 func getImage() {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600))
    for i in 0..<50{
        let url = arrImages[i]
        let elemetView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600))

        elementView.imgVContent.image = UIImage(named: url)
        if let imgColor = elementData.bgColor, imgColor != ""{
            elementView.image = elementView.image?.withColor(UIColor(hexString: imgColor))
            elementView.image.imgColor = UIColor(hexString: imgColor)
        }

        view.addSubview(elementView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your crash log from console and also the code where you are calling this in a loop?

Comment: @Deepika, I have updated this question. Log is only message :"Terminated due to memory issue "

Answer (score 0):

you have mentioned that you have used autorelease pool but I could not find it. May be trying using as below and see if it solves the problem.

In your getImage function, use your for loop with autoreleasepool like below.

```
for i in 0..<50{

    autoreleasepool{
            let url = arrImages[i]
            let elemetView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600))

            elementView.imgVContent.image = UIImage(named: url)
            if let imgColor = elementData.bgColor, imgColor != ""{
                elementView.image = elementView.image?.withColor(UIColor(hexString: imgColor))
                elementView.image.imgColor = UIColor(hexString: imgColor)
            }

            view.addSubview(elementView)
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks you but that's not working. the image size is 1000 * 1000. I think that's problem. but have not find a resolution

Comment: @Anna: I have updated the answer.. The autorelease pool needs to go inside the loop